# How to define additional instance variables with Pytest fixtures

Tags: python

I'd like to run a series of Python unit tests which all share the same `setUp` method. However, a subset of the test require a larger, more specific set of variables. One way to implement this is to define an auxiliary function and call it every time in the 'more specific' tests:

```
import unittest

class TestFixtures(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.a = 1

    def additional_setup(self):
        self.b = 1

    def test_check_value(self):         # Ordinary test
        self.assertEqual(self.a, 1) 

    def test_add_variables(self):       # More specific test requiring 'self.b' to be defined
        self.additional_setup()
        self.assertEqual(self.a + self.b, 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It seems to me like this can be done more elegantly using [Pytest fixtures](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), but none of the examples I saw use fixtures in combination with a conventional `setUp` method. How could I define the additional variables using Pytest fixtures?

**What I've tried so far**

I actually haven't been able to simply define a variable to be used in later test cases using a fixture. For example,

```
import pytest
import unittest

class TestFixtures(unittest.TestCase):
    @pytest.fixture
    def additional_setup_fixture():
        b = 1

    def test_use_fixtures(additional_setup_fixture):
        print b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

yields a `NameError: global name 'b' is not defined.`. How can I define variables for use in tests (either create local variables or instance variables) with Pytest fixtures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approximately equivalent test with Pytest fixtures:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def generate_variables():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a, b

def test_trivial(generate_variables):
    a, b = generate_variables
    assert a+b == 3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

As I understand it, when using Pytest it is no longer necessary for the tests to be methods of a class inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`. Within `test_trivial`, the local variable `generate_variables` is the **output** of the `generate_variables` function (namely, the tuple `(a, b)`) and not the function itself, because it is marked with the `@pytest.fixture` decorator.